# Spanning-Tree-Protocol and BFS? (Distributed Computing)

Tags: distributed-systems, spanning-trees

Given is graph with networks and bridges/switches. We know, the root
Bridge is the bridge with the minimal Bridge-ID. The connections between every bridge and network is 1.

In the lecture slides they calculated the "best"(shortest) path from one network to the root bridge. I assume they used BFS, because it would be the easiest way to calculate the shortest path, but if they used BFS, why is the algorithm called Spanning-Tree-Algorithm?

Comment: What is the algorithm you are referring to?

Comment: @hengxin I am sorry, it is a protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol

Comment: Quote from the wiki "The cost of traversing a path is the sum of the costs of the segments on the path. Different technologies have different default costs". BFS only is not sufficient for computing shortest path on weighted graphs.